# My /opt directory is empty and the app lens is not working, what should I do?

Tags: filesystem, directory, installed-programs

I have 12.10 installed, and I was searching for Transmission one day in the apps lens. It didn't show up, and I was confused; I began searching more in the lens and realized no apps were showing up. As an alternative, I began using the terminal. But since this isn't a real option, and I was confused by the title of the programs (I din't even know it was `chromium-browser` instead of just `chromium`!).
After this, I decided to search for the programs, and where they were installed - so I could execute them that way. Checking [this chapter on the Heirarchy of the Linux Filesystem](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html), I found that the `/opt` directory was most suitable after reading the description.

However, the results of my exploration were not as I had hoped. I navigated to the filesystem and opened the `/opt` directory. I was surprised to see **there was nothing in the folder**. No other folders, no files, nothing. I confirmed that I was allowed to access the file in there, and had sure to check for hidden files and folders.

I can open any applications when I run the command in a Terminal, and I have been pining them for easy access. They open as normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find that most packages installed after installation by the package managers will reside in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/sbin/` Ive always thought as `/opt/` as a place for applications not installed by package managers or "propitiatory" software.

If you want to find where a program lives in the filesystem you can use the `which` command:

```
stephenm@mcr-pc-29392:~$ which chromium-browser 
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

And for the unity app lens problem:

Try removing and installing the application lens again:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-applications

sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was able to discover that `/usr/bin` was a more suitable place - but I didn't find out *why*, so I'm really happy with your answer! :)